# Does Asus Xonar SE 5.1 sound card support Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, sound

Does Ubuntu 20.04 support the Asus Xonar SE 5.1 sound card with HiRes Audio 192kHz/24 bits and 116dB SNR?

Comment: The question you should researching is if the hardware manufacturer supports this device on Linux?  Do they provide a Linux driver for their hardware?

Comment: Install it and try let the rest of us do.